# Hide CSS before scroll

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm working on developing infinite scroll on [my wordpress website](https://imthemoisturizer.com), so I have two "Back-to-top" and "Go-to-bottom" *buttons*. They do their job, but **I would like them to remain hidden until the user scrolls** a bit. Is there a way to do it through CSS? Everything I tried just failed.

Here's the code I'm using for the buttons:

```
<div style="position: fixed; bottom: 70px; right: 25px; z-index: 900">
<a href="#top">
    <img class=" lazyloaded" src="https://imthemoisturizer.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/Top.svg" data-src="https://imthemoisturizer.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/Top.svg" alt="Boton subir" width="40" height="40">
  </a>
</div>
<div style="position: fixed; bottom: 25px; right: 25px; z-index: 900">
  <a href="#fin">
    <img class=" lazyloaded" src="https://imthemoisturizer.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/Bottom.svg" data-src="https://imthemoisturizer.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/Bottom.svg" alt="Boton bajada" width="40" height="40">
</div>
```

I tried adding `margin-top: 100vh`, which would be my ideal solution, and some of the [code shared by Afif Temani here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/css-only-back-to-top-button/), but I can't make it work.

Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: The solution given by @temaniafif in that link seems to work well. When you say you applied 'some of the code' what did you leave out? Note that it works by having body as a grid, the button being the second item of the grid and with sticky property. I don't see any of that essential stuff in the code you have shown. Perhaps you could show us what of that code you did try?

Comment: I tried the `margin-top` part today, but I got nothing out of it. I thought that a simple solution could be adding a margin that exceeded the viewport, but I was wrong.

Comment: I'd suggest looking closely at the code which gives the first feasible solution in that link - there is more to it than just margins and fixed - the grid part and sticky are necessary for example.

Comment: Is CSS-only necessary? IMO it would just overcomplicate things, this is achievable with a few lines of JS. Alternatively, couldn't you just set the markup of the back-to-top button inside the `<footer>`? Then you could use `position: absolute` along with some positioning values on the button with `position: relative` set on the `<footer>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below CSS and JS and it will hide button initially; and show up when you scroll

```
//JavaScript
window.onscroll = function() {toggleScrollButton()};

function toggleScrollButton() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 40 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 40) {
    jQuery(".btn-nav-vertical.top").show();
    jQuery(".btn-nav-vertical.fin").show();
  } else {
    jQuery(".btn-nav-vertical.top").hide();
    jQuery(".btn-nav-vertical.fin").hide();
  }
}

///css -- add in Customizer > CSS
.btn-nav-vertical.top,
.btn-nav-vertical.fin {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: It's weird to mix jQuery & vanilla JS. You can use `.scrollTop()` of jQuery: https://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/. For your logic, alternatively, you can add or remove a CSS class to hide or show the elements.

Comment: You can also use this method: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7557433/274826

Comment: I just tried including the solution provided by @zipal_ , but it didn't work out and I didn't get the buttons to hide.

Comment: did you added the CSS in customizer?

Comment: How could I adapt the one you shared, @Raptor ? I kind of manage with HTML and CSS (still an amateur), but reading JS is like reading cyrillic to me, and even though I'm trying to understand the code, I feel like a toddler learning the alphabet.

Comment: I did add the CSS in Customizer, but for some reason the buttons stayed the same.

Comment: I don't see display none being added.

Comment: @imthemoisturizer see my answer.

Comment: @zipal_ both the CSS and the JS are on, although the buttons plainly disappeared instead of showing after scrolling.

Comment: @imthemoisturizer I see the CSS now. For JS you might have to clear the cache. I don't see it yet. Though where you added your JS?

Comment: I wrote a file on TextEdit, uploaded it to my hosting and executed it on header.php as `<script src="js/hide.js"></script>`

Comment: Can you disable autoptimize plugin for a min and test Or clear cache from it? Seems to be hide.js file is not included on server.

Comment: Sure, I just deleted the cache, Autoptimize should be deactivated now

Comment: you can see in console the hide.js is not uploaded :) or the path of it is wrong. The path of hide js should be absolute. `<script src="yoursite.com/wp-content/themes/[themename]/js/hide.js"></script>`

Comment: The path is now absolute, I didn't think of that, let's hope it loads now!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246812/discussion-between-zipal-and-imthemoisturizer).

Answer (score 0):

The whole solution is a bit complicated. Let me demonstrate in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ejcnyhL6/). Try it.

**HTML**

Added a CSS class to the buttons' DIV.

```
<p>Some contents here</p>
<p>Some contents here</p>
<p>Some contents here</p>
<p>Some contents here</p>
<p>Some contents here</p>
<p>Some contents here</p>
<p>Some contents here</p>
<p>Some contents here</p>
<p>Some contents here</p>
<p>Some contents here</p>
<p>Some contents here</p>
<p>Some contents here</p>
<p>Some contents here</p>
<p>Some contents here</p>
<p>Some contents here</p>
<p>Some contents here</p>
<p>Some contents here</p>
<p>Some contents here</p>
<p>Some contents here</p>
<p class="show-on-scroll">When you scroll to here, display the buttons</p>
<p>Some contents here</p>
<p>Some contents here</p>
<p>Some contents here</p>
<p>Some contents here</p>
<p>Some contents here</p>
<p>Some contents here</p>
<p>Some contents here</p>
<p>Some contents here</p>
<p>Some contents here</p>
<p>Some contents here</p>
<p>Some contents here</p>
<p>Some contents here</p>
<p>Some contents here</p>
<div style="position: fixed; bottom: 70px; right: 25px; z-index: 900" class="btn_controls">
<a href="#top">
    <img class=" lazyloaded" src="https://imthemoisturizer.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/Top.svg" data-src="https://imthemoisturizer.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/Top.svg" alt="Boton subir" width="40" height="40">
  </a>
</div>
<div style="position: fixed; bottom: 25px; right: 25px; z-index: 900" class="btn_controls">
  <a href="#fin">
    <img class=" lazyloaded" src="https://imthemoisturizer.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/Bottom.svg" data-src="https://imthemoisturizer.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/Bottom.svg" alt="Boton bajada" width="40" height="40">
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

I set the buttons to hide initially.

```
.btn_controls {
  display: none;
}
```

**JavaScript (require jQuery)**

If you don't want to use jQuery, you can replace two lines with `$` with vanilla JavaScript `document.getElementByClassName('btn_controls')` bla bla bla.

```
// Detect request animation frame
var scroll = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
             // IE Fallback
             function(callback){ window.setTimeout(callback, 1000/60)};
var elementsToShow = document.querySelectorAll('.show-on-scroll'); 

function loop() {

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(elementsToShow, function(element){
      if (isElementInViewport(element)) {
        $('.btn_controls').show();
      } else {
        $('.btn_controls').hide();
      }
    });

    scroll(loop);
}

// Call the loop for the first time
loop();

// Helper function from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7557433/274826
function isElementInViewport(el) {
  // special bonus for those using jQuery
  if (typeof jQuery === "function" && el instanceof jQuery) {
    el = el[0];
  }
  var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  return (
    (rect.top <= 0
      && rect.bottom >= 0)
    ||
    (rect.bottom >= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
      rect.top <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight))
    ||
    (rect.top >= 0 &&
      rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight))
  );
}
```

p.s. IMO as you're developing websites, you must learn JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I feel like I'm getting closer! I added the code to my staging site (https://pruebas.imthemoisturizer.com) and the buttons totally disappeared instead of showing after `<p class="show-on-scroll">`. I'm working on my JS skills, it just seems way more difficult than HTML and CSS to me, so I really appreciate your patience and help.

Comment: Lots of JS errors, you should check Developer Console in the browser. Fix all errors first. And you didn't mention you're using WordPress. Deploying JS to WordPress theme is different than a plain HTML page.

Comment: I did include the Wordpress tag on the original post, but maybe I should have been more explicit. Is there a way to tweak the code you shared to adapt it to WP so that the buttons appear after scrolling?

Comment: It depends on your WP theme structure. Learn how to modify a WP theme first.